# Circuitikz - adjusting length of a single block

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[twoportshape, t=$\frac{T_s \, (z+1)}{2 \, (z-1)}$] (int1) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I adjust the length of the twoportshape such that the text fits in it **without** changing its height?

This seems like a very basic thing, but I was unable to find a solution in the documentation.

The documentation suggests using

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.4cm}
```

But this does increase both, the length and the height of the blocks. Also, it is applied globally to all blocks and not just a single one.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One should note that a major difference between circuitikz and tikz circuits is that tikz enlarges all of its nodes to fit the contents.  Circuitikz does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the idea between the `twoport`s is to have a nice group of blocks all the same size --- in case you want just to draw blocks around generic text or formulas, the answer given by Zarko is the correct one --- pure Ti*k*Z suffices and it's more flexible.

Anyway, if your bigger block is the odd one, you *can* change its width with the undocumented key `bipoles/twoport/width` (default 0.7, relative to the base length). Notice that if you use the node form you *need* to add the `circuitikz` part in front.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[twoportshape, t=$\frac{T_s \, (z+1)}{2 \, (z-1)}$, circuitikz/bipoles/twoport/width=1.0] (int1) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When used (more naturally) as a `path` element, you have for example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[twoport, t=$\frac{T_s \, (z+1)}{2 \, (z-1)}$, bipoles/twoport/width=1.0, >]
    ++(3,0) to[amp, box, , >, -o] ++(2,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why you not draw your box as ordinary `tikz` box?

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw, thick, minimum size=9mm] (int1) {$\frac{T_s(z+1)}{2(z-1)}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]